# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Cursor' and 'Cursor'

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I want to be able to store two collections in variable to be able to view and sort through them. However, I seem to be getting the error above.
My code is in python and look like this:

```
  from pymongo import MongoClient

  db = MongoClient('10.39.165.193', 27017)['mean-dev']
  cursor1 = db.Build_Progress.find()
  cursor2 = db.build_lookup.find()
  joincursors = cursor1+ cursor2

 for document in cook:
     print(document)
```

Comment: `joincursors = cursor1+ cursor2` what are you trying to do here? The error it clearly telling you that you can't use the operator `+` with `Cursor objects`

Comment: Your right. I was looking for a way to join the cursors together so that I can  view them and use them as a single cursor. The method I used was clearly wrong, I was looking for an alternative or a method to do a similar thing. Sorry for not clearly identifying the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [`chain`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) the two cursors like this:

```
from itertools import chain

for document in chain(cursor1, cursor2):
    print(document)
```

Comment: Thanks that worked well!! is there a way however to store the two cursors into one cursor or variable?